# Iterate over array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON string like this

```
 var json =  '{ "Comments": 
    [
      { "Id" : 1,"Comment" : "Test comment","Name" : "Yogesh","Child" : 0},
      { "Id" : 2,"Comment" : "Test comment II","Name" : "Yogesh","Child" : 0}
    ] 
    }';
```

and I'm trying to iterate over the objects as such:

```
var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON(json);

var html = "";    
for (comment in parsedJSON.Comments) {
  html += "Id: " + comment.Id;
  html += "Comment: " + comment.Comment;
  html += "Name: " + comment.Name;
  html += "Child: " + comment.Child;
  html += "<br/>";
}
```

But here `comment` in for loop becomes `0` and `1` only, I mean not an object but just a string, how can I iterate over this array?

Comment: You are not iterating over JSON, you are iterating over a JavaScript array. I corrected your question accordingly. You should use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) for that. You might also read about [arrays in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var json = '{ "Comments": [{ "Id" : 1,"Comment" : "Test comment","Name" : "Yogesh","Child" : 0},{ "Id" : 2,"Comment" : "Test comment II","Name" : "Yogesh","Child" : 0}] }';

var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON(json), // jsonData should json
    html = "",
    comments =parsedJSON.Comments; // keeping reference of parsedJSON and its an Array

// Here key will give 0, 1 etc ie. index of array

for (var key in comments) {
    html += "Id: " + comments[key].Id;
    html += "Comment: " + comments[key].Comment;
    html += "Name: " + comments[key].Name;
    html += "Child: " + comments[key].Child;
    html += "<br/>";
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jrg2k/1/)**

Comment: Giving code that doesn't work (ReferenceError: comments is not defined) with no explanation? Boo.

Comment: @Kolink: Perhaps a basic knowledge of correcting JS typos is assumed in the javascript tag :) I have changed the ";" to a "," to rectify the declaration error.

Comment: +1 for showing an interesting alternative to basic for-next indexing.

Comment: also, see this for a `forEach` varsion of this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Jrg2k/5/

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have misunderstood how `for..in` loops work. `comment` will iteratively be the keys of the array. In any case, you should not use `for..in` on an array, only objects - and even then with caution.

```
var l = parsedJSON.Comments.length, i, comment;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    comment = parseJSON.Comments[i];
    // do stuff with comment
}
```

Comment: I had tried it very first, but `parsedJSON.Comments` doesn't had any definition for length.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try this:

```
     var JsonData =  { "Comments":
        [
          { "Id" : 1,"Comment" : "Test comment","Name" : "Yogesh","Child" : 0},
          { "Id" : 2,"Comment" : "Test comment II","Name" : "Yogesh","Child" : 0}
        ]
        };

    var html = "";    
    for (var i = 0; i < JsonData.Comments.length; i++) {
      comment = JsonData.Comments[i];
      html += "Id: " + comment.Id;
      html += " Comment: " + comment.Comment;
      html += " Name: " + comment.Name;
      html += " Child: " + comment.Child;
      html += "<br/>";
    }

alert(html);
```

Comment: what didn't work exactly? because i tested it and it worked for me, here is my test: http://jsfiddle.net/VYTpG/

Comment: Actually you didn't get the question right, I wasn't talking about a JSON object that you have, I was talking about a JSON string see this http://jsfiddle.net/VYTpG/1/ but anyways thanx for help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.each`:

```
var html = ""; 
$.each(parsedJSON.Comments, function(i, comment) {
   html += "Id: " + comment.Id;
   html += "Comment: " + comment.Comment;
   html += "Name: " + comment.Name;
   html += "Child: " + comment.Child;
   html += "<br/>";
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `$.map`:

```
var html = $.map(parsedJSON.Comments, function(comment, i) {
   return "Id: " + comment.Id +
          "Comment: " + comment.Comment +
          "Name: " + comment.Name +
          "Child: " + comment.Child + 
          "<br/>";
}).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments holds an array with two elements.

```
{ "Comments" : [ { 1 }, { 2 }]  ...
```

So you can access it with

```
for (var i = 0, len = parsedJSON.Comments.length; i < len; i++) {
    html += "Id: " + parsedJSON.Comments[i].Id;
    html += "Comment: " + parsedJSON.Comments[i].Comment;
    html += "Name: " + parsedJSON.Comments[i].Name;
    html += "Child: " + parsedJSON.Comments[i].Child;
    html += "<br/>";
}
```